# Set Target Location for Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am compiling a C project on AIX with the GNU make tool and want the `.o` files to be installed in the `build` directory under my project. However, the current configuration puts the `.o`'s in the `project` directory where the `makefile` is located. The directory structure is:

`project`

- `src/`
- `build/`
- `makefile`

The source files are in `src/`.

The `makefile` contains the following text:

```
src = /PATHTO/project/src/
build = /PATHTO/project/build/

objects = $(build)config.o #(...)

$(build)main : $(objects)
   cc -o main $(objects)

$(build)config.o : $(src)config.c $(src)config.h
   cc -c $(src)config.c
```

This `makefile` works but `config.o` and `main` are both placed under `project` instead of under `project/build`.

Thank you.

Comment: The `-o` flag for the compiler is setting the output path.

Comment: That makefile does not work correctly actually. It can't correctly rebuild only things that need to be rebuilt because the `$(build)config.o` target doesn't generate the correct output file. Fixing the question being asked here will actually fix that though.

Comment: Actually I don't see how it works at all since the` $(build)main` recipe should be trying to use object files that don't exist where it is looking for them. It tries to use `$(build)config.o ...` but the actual `.o` files are at the toplevel instead.

Comment: shouldn't there be `/`s between path var names and file names? e.g. `$(build)/config.o` instead of `$(build)config.o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things:

- when building `main` the folder is not specified; it defaults to current directory(`/PATHTO/project`)
- when compiling `config.c` the output is not specified; it also defaults to current directory

Now why it works i'm not sure because it should not find `$(build)config.o` (unless you copied it there manually).

To get things working modify your rules to:

```
$(build)main : $(objects)
    cc -o $@ $?

$(build)config.o : $(src)config.c $(src)config.h
    cc -c -o $@ $<
```

- `$@` is the rule's *target*
- `$?` are the target's *dependents*
- `$<` is the first *dependent* (note that this is not to be used when the target has multiple `.c` dependents

Of course things can be taken further:

- define a `clean` target
- use pattern rules

as described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Answer (score 1):

the correction is simple

The location of the resulting files needs to be specifically defined.

That location is defined by using the '-o' parameter

so use:

```
src = /PATHTO/project/src/
build = /PATHTO/project/build/

objects = $(build)config.o #(...)

$(build)main : $(objects)
    CC -o $@ $(objects) 

$(build)config.o : $(src)config.c $(src)config.h
    CC  -c $< -o $@ -I.
```